# develop mac app swipe from one ViewController to another with Swift(not use storyboard)

Tags: macos, swift

i'm the new one develop mac app.When i want to do what i say in title,presentViewController method but with an error said i pass the wrong parameter,but what pass is total the same as what it want.
The error message said "Cannot invoke 'presentViewController' with an argument list of type..."

```
import Cocoa

class MainViewController: NSViewController {

    var uploadViewController: UploadViewController!
    @IBOutlet weak var HostFileList: NSScrollView!
    @IBOutlet weak var AddFileToHost: NSButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var DeleteFileFromHost: NSButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var Host: NSTextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var Port: NSTextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var ConnectServer: NSButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var UploadFile: NSButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do view setup here.
    }

}

extension MainViewController {
    @IBAction func UploadFile(sender: AnyObject) {
        var uploadViewController = UploadViewController(nibName: "MasterViewController", bundle: nil)
        self.presentViewController(uploadViewController, animator: NSTableViewAnimationOptions.SlideRight)

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On OSX, there is no UINavigationController doing the push/pop stuff and the animation for you!

So you have to do it yourself using ViewAnimations and removeFromSuperview and addSubview to switch out the views manually.

there also a lot of ready made ways for you to do iOS-like stuff on the mac: https://www.google.de/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=uinavigationcontroller+osx&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&gfe_rd=cr&ei=T3OjVfeqPNfIgATS64G4Dw

The most lightweight at first glance looks to be:
https://github.com/bfolder/BFNavigationController

(note: Im not the author and I dont even know him! :D)